# Use custom User object that does NOT inherit from UserEntity for Authentication and Authorization in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have an existing database which contains a User table.  The database is already in use by the Web API for a mobile app and for several reasons it is difficult to make changes to it.

I need to develop an ASP.NET Core MVC website which allows users to authenticate using the same credentials stored in this User table.

I would like to use the built in ASP.NET Core Identity system for Authorisation.  I can write my own Authentication methods to work with my custom User entity.

In my Startup class I have-

```
services.AddIdentity<User, MyRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>();
```

But `IServiceCollection.AddIdentity` only takes types of UserEntity, if I make my `User` class a subclass of `UserEntity` I will get errors because my User table in the database does not contain all of the `UserEntity` properties.

Is there a way to avoid having to modify the User table in my database but still use the built in Identity system?

Comment: You can use any model you want, but then you need to implement the stores yourself. See https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore.cs#L96-L106 on how the default EF Core provider is implemented

Comment: Thanks @Tseng i'll take a look at that

Comment: @Tseng Don't suppose you know of any examples of where these stores have been implemented for a custom Model? Thank you

Comment: They are implemented in the exact same way as the linked source for Identity.EntityFramework. The models used by Identity are nothing else than POCO objects. The store consists of multiple interfaces, depending on which features you want to support (like 2Factor Authentication, Password support, etc. ). Once you have written then you can use `AddStores` extensions  method to register the store (same as IdentityEF  provider does here https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs#L24-L29)